# custom post meta not saving in custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

i have written a code for my custom meta post. the meta post is check box showing just below the custom post. but when i try to save it. it don not save and leave check box blank.i dont know why its not saving?
Checkbox it using from another custom post.

`add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'cd_meta_box_add_alert' );
    function cd_meta_box_add_alert()
    {   
    add_meta_box( 'my-meta-box-id-2', 'Select People for blog',
    'cd_meta_box_cb_alert', 'alert' , 'normal', 'high' );
    }

    function cd_meta_box_cb_alert()
    {
    // $post is already set, and contains an object: the WordPress post
    global $alert;
    $valuesalert = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
    // We'll use this nonce field later on when saving.
    wp_nonce_field( 'alert_my_meta_box_nonce', 'alert_meta_box_nonce' );
    $checkalert = isset( $valuesalert['people_to_alert'] ) ? esc_attr($valuesalert['people_to_alert'][0] ) : '';

    $people_array_alert = unserialize($valuesalert['people_to_alert'][0]);
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'lowenbaumpeople',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order'   => 'ASC',
    );
    $queryalert = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $queryalert->have_posts() ) : $queryalert->the_post();
    if ( !empty($people_array_alert) && is_array($people_array_alert) ) {
    $checkalert = (in_array($post->ID, $people_array_alert)) ? 'on' : '';
    }


    <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" name="people_to_blog[]" <?php checked( $checkalert, 'on' ); ?> />
    <label for="people_to_blog"><?php the_title();?></label>

    add_action( 'save_post', 'cd_meta_box_save_alert' );
    function cd_meta_box_save_alert( $post_id )
    {   global $post;
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return; 
    if( !isset( $_POST['alert_meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['alert_meta_box_nonce'], 'alert_my_meta_box_nonce' ) ) return;  
      if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;

    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'people_to_alert', $_POST['people_to_alert'] );


}`

i have turn on the debug mode and found these error

[13-Sep-2015 11:09:59 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /home/cdrossen6800/public_html/lowenbaumlaw/wp-includes/capabilities.php on line 1190
[13-Sep-2015 11:09:59 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: people_to_alert in /home/cdrossen6800/public_html/lowenbaumlaw/wp-content/themes/lowenbaum/functions.php on line 819
[13-Sep-2015 11:10:00 UTC] PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /home/cdrossen6800/public_html/lowenbaumlaw/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 957

Comment: Try to debug your code with error reporting turned on. Now we can't help you.

Comment: i have enable the debug mode and getting this error. 
[13-Sep-2015 10:11:00 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /home/cdrossen6800/public_html/lowenbaumlaw/wp-includes/capabilities.php on line 1190
[13-Sep-2015 10:11:00 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: people_to_alert in /home/cdrossen6800/public_html/lowenbaumlaw/wp-content/themes/lowenbaum/functions.php on line 819
[13-Sep-2015 10:11:02 UTC] PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /home/cdrossen6800/public_html/lowenbaumlaw/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 957